# Reading from stdin in Python subprocess hangs in C++/Python IPC

Tags: python, c++, pipe, stdin

I am working on a C++ application which starts a Python subprocess and tries to establish a communication between parent (C++) and child (Python). In particular I am writing the Python part in order to integrate with the C++ application which I haven't written and I cannot change. I already implemented a socket solution to handle the communication but I need also to support the communication using pipes.

My problem is that I can write from Python to stdout and the message is received by the C++ application. However the Python subprocess can't read the message sent by the parent process. I tried to extrapolate the parts of the code that I think are the most relevant to describe the problem:

**C++**

```
void startSubprocess(char* program, char** arguments)
{
    int p_stdout;
    int p_stdin;
    int p_stderr;

    int out[2];
    int in[2];
    int err[2];

    char** arguments;
    char* program;

    pipe(out);
    pipe(in);
    pipe(err);
    posix_spawn_file_actions_init(&action);
    posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose(&action, out[1]);
    posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose(&action, in[0]);
    posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose(&action, err[0]);
    posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2(&action, out[0], 0);
    posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2(&action, in[1], 1);
    posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2(&action, err[1], 2);
    std::vector<char *> vars_c(vars.size() + 1); 

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != vars.size(); ++i) {
        vars_c[i] = &vars[i][0];
    }

    vars_c[vars.size()] = NULL;
    string cwd = __getcwd();

    if (directory.size() > 0)
        chdir(directory.c_str());

    if (posix_spawnp(&pid, program, &action, NULL, arguments, vars_c.data())) {
        cleanup();
        pid = 0;
        if (directory.size() > 0) chdir(cwd.c_str());
        return false;
    }

    if (directory.size() > 0) chdir(cwd.c_str());

    p_stdin = out[1];
    p_stdout = in[0];
    p_stderr = err[0];
}

void write(const char* buf, int len)
{
    write(p_stdout, buf, len);
}

void read(char* buf, int len)
{
    read(p_stdin, buf, len);
}
```

**Python**

```
def writeMsg(msg):
    sys.stdout.write(msg)
    sys.stdout.flush()


def readMsg():
    msg = sys.stdin.read()
```

When I run the application the parent process (C++) reads the message sent by the Python subprocess. After that the Python subprocess is not able to read from sys.stdin . It waits forever till the timeout.

When I run the C++ application I can see that out = [3,4] and in=[5,6] so p_stdin=6 and p_stdout=3. I am testing the application in Ubuntu 14.04.

I have been trying few other approaches (using os.fdopen and os.read) but without success. Any suggestion to solve this problem is welcomed. Thanks!

**EDIT**

I have realised that I skipped some important information to understand the problem. The main application and the Python subprocess need to continuosly communicate and read and write message to send and receive in a loop till termination. The code looks something like this (just for description purpose):

**C++**

```
int communicate()
{
    // skip var init etc

    // launch subprocess
    startSubprocess(program, arguments);
    while(1)
    { 
        // read message sent by subprocess
        read(msg, len);  
        if(msg == "quit")
            break;

        // part of the code that generates msg2

        //  send a message to subproc  
        write(msg2, len2);
    } 
    return 1;     
}
```

**Python**

```
def communicate():
    while True:
        # generate msg to send to C++

        writeMsg(msg)
        msgRcv = readMsg()
        if msgRcv == 'quit':
            break
    return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realised that sys.stdin.read() hangs till EOF before returning the message. By replacing msg = sys.stdin.read() with

```
msg = sys.stdin.readline()
```

my application works as expected. The messages sent by the application are separated by newline '\n' character so this approach works for me. In other cases I think that reading one character at a time using

```
msg += sys.stdin.read(1)
```

will avoid the program to hang waiting for EOF.

There are already several answers about this difference between read and readline. Unfortunately during my tests when I tried readline the client was terminated by the parent process before reading.